# Incrementing value based on number of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Objective

- In the first function `countCorrect` I'm trying to increment the `count` based on the number of times a user clicks on a button with a class of `is-correct`
- The end goal is to pass the value of `count` to the second function `changeTotalCorrect` in order to update the HTML on the page

## Problem

- When click a button with a correct answer and the value of `count` logged to the console is 0, when I expect an integer between 1-10.

### scripts.js

```
function countCorrect() {
    var count = 0;

    $(".is-correct").on("click", function(){
        count = count++;
        console.log("Answer is correct.");
        console.log(count); // Expect an integer from 1-10
    });

    return count;
}

function changeTotalCorrect(func) {
    var count = countCorrect(); // Expect an integer from 1-10
    $(".highlight").html(count); // Change the HTML to reflect the new number
}

changeTotalCorrect();
```

### index.html

```
<div class="buttons">
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--one is-correct">${{ content.price_correct|int }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--two">${{ content.price_incorrect_one|int }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--three">${{ content.price_incorrect_two|int }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--four">${{ content.price_incorrect_three|int }}</button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the click listener outside of the function like this:

```
var count = 0;

$(".is-correct").on("click", function(){
    count++;
    console.log("Answer is correct.");
    console.log(count); // Expect an integer from 1-10
    changeTotalCorrect();
});


function changeTotalCorrect(func) {
    $(".highlight").html(count); // Change the HTML to reflect the new number
}

changeTotalCorrect();
```

```js
var count = 0;

$(".is-correct").on("click", function(){
    count++;
    console.log("Answer is correct.");
    console.log(count); // Expect an integer from 1-10
    changeTotalCorrect();
});


function changeTotalCorrect(func) {
    $(".highlight").html(count); // Change the HTML to reflect the new number
}

changeTotalCorrect();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--one is-correct">${{ content.price_correct|int }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--two">${{ content.price_incorrect_one|int }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--three">${{ content.price_incorrect_two|int }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn--option btn--four">${{ content.price_incorrect_three|int }}</button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `jQuery` https://jsfiddle.net/jeogdzh7/

```js
var cnt = 0;

$('button').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('cnt', cnt);
})

$('button').click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('is-correct')){
      $(this).html( "Count " + (parseInt($(this).attr('cnt')) + 1 ));
      $(this).attr('cnt', (parseInt($(this).attr('cnt')) + 1));
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--one is-correct">Count 0</button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--two">Count 0</button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--three">Count 0</button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--four">Count 0</button>
</div>
```

I'm using `attribute` to store the count of `click`.
`.hasClass` is being used for checking the class present in `button`.

Rather than having two individual function to update the count, I've done it using within `click` function.

**Updated Code**

```
$('button').click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('is-correct')){
      $(this)
        .attr('cnt', (parseInt($(this).attr('cnt')) + 1))
        .html( "Count " + $(this).attr('cnt'));
   }
 });
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
count = count++;
```

It should be:

```
count++;
```

Using the `++` operator after a variable works by evaluating to the current value (0 in this case) and *then* incrementing the value stored in the variable. It's the evaluated value (0) that you were incorrectly assigning back to the variable.